# Caliburn.Micro: Bind to list with first item as null

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, drop-down-menu, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro to bind a combobox to a list of items. Let's say for example they are Employees. I want the (fairly commonplace) behaviour where the first item isn't an employee, but is either `null` or something else that represents when nothing has been selected.

I don't really want to hack it where the first employee is named "Please select" with an ID of zero, so I would appreciate your opinion. My preference would be for the first item in the list to be `null`, in which case my validation (either requiring a value be selected or recording that no value was selected) is very straightforward (I'll bind `SelectedItem` to a property on my view model.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or is this more of a hypothetical question?

Comment: So far I've got a POC working with the hack I mentioned earlier. I'm working on something at the moment where I have a generic list of IListItem but am actually putting either PleaseSelectListItemViewModel or EmployeeViewModel in the list I'm binding to, to see if CM will choose a different view for each, accordingly. It's a lot of code though so I'd be interested to hear if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Well, I can't see why there would be a lot of code - it depends (do you *NEED* a view for each combo item or can you just use a standard itemtemplate?), I'll post what works for me

Answer (score 2):

I've just created a standard itemtemplate for the control where I've bound a `TextBlock` to the list items `DisplayName`, then I've set the `FallbackValue` to a nice message

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SomeSelection" SelectedValuePath="Value" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action DroppedDown(SomeSelection)]">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, FallbackValue='Please select a value'}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The I populate the items in the VM

```
    // Standard property
    private ObservableCollection<SomeObject> _SomeSelection = null;
    public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> SomeSelection
    {
        get { return _SomeSelection; }
        set
        {
            if (_SomeSelection != value)
            {
                _SomeSelection = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SomeSelection);
            }
        }
    }

    // Instantiate and add some test items
    SomeSelection = new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();
    SomeSelection.Add(null);
    SomeSelection.Add(new SomeObject("Hello", 0));
    SomeSelection.Add(new SomeObject("World", 1));
```

The SomeObject class is just a test class:

```
public class SomeObject : IHaveDisplayName
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public SomeObject(string name, int value)
    {
        DisplayName = name;
        Value = value;
    }

}
```

The only thing I can't get working yet is the selection of the 'Please select a value' item by default. You might need a dirty hack to get this working since the first item in the list is a null reference...

Also since CM's default convention for ComboBox is to pass SelectedItem not SelectedValue to actions, you get the selected item being passed to any methods, which for a null combobox item appears to be the combobox item itself rather than a null. Strange but understandable!
What did your approach look like?